# USING expression to convert table column type - Rails postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

On my development's sqlite3 DB, I don't have the following error, but I do when I try to db:migrate in my Heroku instance.

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.4755
== 20150512123847 ChangePricetoDecimal: migrating =============================
-- change_column(:products, :price, :decimal)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "price" cannot be cast automatically to type numeric
HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.
```

I was told that this [website has the answer](http://webjazz.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-alter-columns-in-postgresql.html), but I'm struggling to figure out where and how I implement the solution. Do I do it by console command? Or do I add it to a file then try the db migrate? 
If needed, the [whole of the project is on GitHub](https://github.com/dadiletta/JoeRox).

Comment: Another good example why you should develop on the same platform that you deploy on.

Comment: I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name, develop with PostgreSQL if you're using production PostgreSQL. I would say use MySQL in production if you want to stick with sqilte3 for development, but Heroku is all PostgreSQL. That should tell you something, use PostgreSQL.

Comment: Cool, I will look for resources on how to switch from sqlite3 to PostgreSQL within the development environment. It's an intimidating task but it's just the kind of thing I need to learn. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just dropped my database and reformed it so that there was no need to navigate the explicit conversion problems we were having
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql

Answer (score 2):

Try updating your ChangePriceToNumeric migration with something like:

```
class ChangePriceToNumeric < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        change_column :products, :price, 'numeric USING CAST(price AS numeric)'
    end
end
```

Then run your migrations.

As stated in the comments, I would try use the same database for development and production.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Modifying 20150512123847_change_priceto_decimal.rb with the code you provided has produced the following error:

    rake aborted!
    NameError: uninitialized constant ChangePricetoDecimal

Comment: Could you try changing your migration filename to **20150512123847_change_price_to_decimal.rb** (note the underscore after **price**) and running your migrations again?

Comment: Still the same message. Don't I need to generate a new migration file via console command? I'm not sure...